# PHP(form) email not sending correctly with html design

Tags: php, html, forms, email

**Problems (only after hitting submit)**

1. The email is not displaying the html form or its results, it's only sending the number "1" in multiple emails
2. The form results are displaying on the next page (need to send to other page)

I have a form on my website and I wanted to send the results from that form to my email. However, I want the results to be in the same format that the form was in. So I'm not familiar with php and I researched how to send an email and I got that working. After looking at it I realized that it would be much easier to read the form information if it was in a form. I copied and pasted the html over to the php and put it all inside of the print tag. I went further and inserted readonly tags inside of the inputs on the form before I inserted placeholder tags to display the form results. The issue I'm having is that when I hit submit the form is displayed on the next page and the email I receive only has the number 1 inside of the email body...and I get several emails at once with the same message.

***Extra:***

1.The php code is below, I only put placeholders on the first three inputs because I just needed a couple inputs to test if the script worked.

2.The original html form(not below) has "name" tags so the results I enter are displaying when I hit submit.

3.If you read the code you only need to pay attention to the first three inputs, all the rest are there for a visual purpose. Later on I wanted to see how much of the form I could put inside of the email and how much styling as well.

```
<?php

$to = 'anyemail@email.com';

$subject = "New Mortgage Form ($name)";

$message = Print'
<form>
    <div id="AppInfo">
        <br>
        <span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 1.2em;">Applicant Information</span> <br><br>

        Name: <input type="text" title="name" placeholder="' .$_POST['name']  . '" readonly> <br> <br>
        Address: <input type="text" title="address" placeholder="' .$_POST['address']  . '" readonly> <br> <br>
        Rent/Own: <input type="text" title="rentown" placeholder="' .$_POST['rentown']  . '" readonly> <br><br>

        How Long: <input type="text" title="length" readonly> <br><br>
        Prior Address: <input type="text" title="prior" readonly> <br><br>
        DOB: <input type="text" title="dob" readonly> <br><br>
        Marital Status: <input type="text" title="marital" readonly> <br><br>
        SSN: <input type="number" title="estValue" readonly> <br><br>
        Home:<input type="tel" title="home" readonly> <br><br>
        Cell: <input type="tel" title="cell" readonly> <br><br>
        Employer: <input type="text" title="emp" readonly> <br><br>
        Position: <input type="text" title="empPosition" readonly> <br><br>
        Address: <input type="text" title="empAddress" readonly> <br><br>
        Monthly Salary: <input type="number" title="empSalary" readonly> <br><br>
        Date Hired: <input type="date" title="empHired" readonly> <br><br>
        Commission, Overtime, Child Support, etc: <br>
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type="text" title="c.o.c.e" readonly> <br><br>
        Wk <input type="number" title="work" readonly> <br><br>
        Fax <input type="number" title="fax" readonly> <br><br>
        Self Employed: &nbsp Yes<input type="checkbox" title="seYes" readonly> &nbsp&nbsp No<input type="checkbox" title="seNo" readonly> <br><br>
        How Long: <input type="text" title="seLength" readonly> <br><br>
    </div>

    <br><br><br>

    <div id="MoDebt">
        <span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 1.2em;">Monthly Debts</span>
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <br><br>
        Rent/Mortgage Payment: <input type="text" title="Rent or Mortgage Payment Amount Monthly"> <br> <br>
        Car Payment: <input type="text" title="Car Payment Amount Monthly"> <br> <br>
        Make/Model/Year: <input type="text" title="Make of car/Model of car/Year of car"> <br><br>
        Student Loans: <input type="text" title="Student Loans Amount Monthly"> <br><br>
        Credit Cards: <input type="text" title="Credit Cards Amount Monthly"> <br><br>
        Child Support: <input type="text" title="Child Support Amount Monthly"> <br><br>
        Other: <input type="text" title="Other Debt Amounts Monthly"> <br><br>
    </div>';



// send email
mail($to, $subject, $message);

?>
```

Comment: I just found an alternative option: Attachments! However, I would still want to figure out this current question...

Comment: It might be because you are printing the message. Which wil return true. So remove the print there.

Comment: Follow this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and update the script,
Your script sending 1 because the headers are not present in the script, so add appropriate headers and send email.

Comment: you are not assigning the form to the $message variable: you are assigning the print result of that form to the variable. Just remove `Print` at the beginning of the $message variable and it will be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:
You are actually setting the $message variable to the result of the Print ''; call which always returns a 1, which will be sent as your message.

Second problem is due to the same print call too.

You should try this I mean :

```
    <?php

$to = 'anyemail@email.com';

$subject = "New Mortgage Form ($name)";

$message = '
<form>
    <div id="AppInfo">
        <br>
        <span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 1.2em;">Applicant Information</span> <br><br>

        Name: <input type="text" title="name" placeholder="' .$_POST['name']  . '" readonly> <br> <br>
        Address: <input type="text" title="address" placeholder="' .$_POST['address']  . '" readonly> <br> <br>
        Rent/Own: <input type="text" title="rentown" placeholder="' .$_POST['rentown']  . '" readonly> <br><br>

        How Long: <input type="text" title="length" readonly> <br><br>
        Prior Address: <input type="text" title="prior" readonly> <br><br>
        DOB: <input type="text" title="dob" readonly> <br><br>
        Marital Status: <input type="text" title="marital" readonly> <br><br>
        SSN: <input type="number" title="estValue" readonly> <br><br>
        Home:<input type="tel" title="home" readonly> <br><br>
        Cell: <input type="tel" title="cell" readonly> <br><br>
        Employer: <input type="text" title="emp" readonly> <br><br>
        Position: <input type="text" title="empPosition" readonly> <br><br>
        Address: <input type="text" title="empAddress" readonly> <br><br>
        Monthly Salary: <input type="number" title="empSalary" readonly> <br><br>
        Date Hired: <input type="date" title="empHired" readonly> <br><br>
        Commission, Overtime, Child Support, etc: <br>
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type="text" title="c.o.c.e" readonly> <br><br>
        Wk <input type="number" title="work" readonly> <br><br>
        Fax <input type="number" title="fax" readonly> <br><br>
        Self Employed: &nbsp Yes<input type="checkbox" title="seYes" readonly> &nbsp&nbsp No<input type="checkbox" title="seNo" readonly> <br><br>
        How Long: <input type="text" title="seLength" readonly> <br><br>
    </div>

    <br><br><br>

    <div id="MoDebt">
        <span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 1.2em;">Monthly Debts</span>
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <br><br>
        Rent/Mortgage Payment: <input type="text" title="Rent or Mortgage Payment Amount Monthly"> <br> <br>
        Car Payment: <input type="text" title="Car Payment Amount Monthly"> <br> <br>
        Make/Model/Year: <input type="text" title="Make of car/Model of car/Year of car"> <br><br>
        Student Loans: <input type="text" title="Student Loans Amount Monthly"> <br><br>
        Credit Cards: <input type="text" title="Credit Cards Amount Monthly"> <br><br>
        Child Support: <input type="text" title="Child Support Amount Monthly"> <br><br>
        Other: <input type="text" title="Other Debt Amounts Monthly"> <br><br>
    </div>';



// send email
mail($to, $subject, $message);

?>
```

Comment: Wow, this one word got me one step closer, I now have the html code sending to my email but I don't have it processed as html, it's simply text. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help. For that you'll need to use headers, which is mentioned in the answer below. Make sure you enter the correct values in the header.

Comment: or refer to the headers at [https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/](https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

Answer (score 1):

You need set Content-type: text/html to header email. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)
```

Comment: The other comment by Sabeer Sulaiman got me the html code sent to my email, I was hoping your comment would help me see the html composed visually but with the addition of the headers I am no longer receiving the email. Like there is no email being sent what-so-ever, so I'm not sure if it is the headers code or maybe something isn't working server-side at the moment. Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: I'm show you headers for example you need set Content-type:text/html; Content-type say mail how parse you email. If you copy this header you don't get email because To mail not right
 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
for you.